# List to Dictionary with key to be a String Counter

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary

I am new to python and was trying to implement a dictionary from a list with the key value to be a string counter

ex. the list is `['a','b','c']`

I want this list to be displayed as

dict `{'A1':'a','A2':'b','A3':'c'}`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Given I understand your question correctly you want for the *i*-th element, a key-value pair `'Ai':c` with `c` the character at position *i*. You can use *dictionary comprehension*:

```
{'A%s'%i:e for i,e in enumerate(data,1)}
```

Running this in the interpreter:

```
>>> data = ['a','b','c']
>>> {'A%s'%i:e for i,e in enumerate(data,1)}
{'A2': 'b', 'A3': 'c', 'A1': 'a'}
```

This is dictionary comprehension. Dictionary comprehension has as syntax:

```
{key(element):value(element) for element in iterable}
```

Where `key` and `value` are expressions that do something with `element`. For each element in the `iterable`. It will evaluate the expression and associate the value with the derived key.

Comment: Hey willem thanks for the quick response, could you please explain the syntax you just used